# How can I control which cells can receive user input and the order in which the cursor moves to each cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like for the user to only be allowed to input values into the cells listed below in the following order:

D3,C3,B9,B3,E2,D4,G4,I4,D5,G5,I5,D6,G6,I6,D7,G7,I7,D8,G8 and I8.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open excel and select the cells mentioned by you. You can do this by keeping Ctrl key pressed while selecting the cells. Now right click and select format cells and go to the protection tab. In the protection tab, uncheck the Locked check box. Now protect the sheet and make sure that you check the option 'Select Unlocked Cells' (second checkbox in the list)

Here is the code to control the order using vba

1. Right-click on the sheet1 tab and "View Code".
2. Paste the following code into that sheet module.

   ```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
   On Error GoTo enditall
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   i = Array("D3", "C3", "B9", "B3", "E2", "D4", "G4", "I4", "D5", "G5", "I5", "D6", "G6", "I6", "D7", "G7", "I7", "D8", "G8", "I8")
   k = Replace(Target.Cells.Address, "$", "")
   If k = i(j) Then
   Sheet1.Unprotect
   Sheet1.Range(i(j)).Locked = True
   Sheet1.Range(i(j + 1)).Locked = False
   Sheet1.Range(i(j + 1)).Select
   j = j + 1
   Sheet1.Protect
   End If
   enditall:
   Sheet1.Protect
   Application.EnableEvents = True
   End Sub
   ```
3. Now right click on sheet1 in the same window and select insert. From the insert menu click on Module. Now select the create module and paste the following code.

   ```
   Public j

   Sub Settings()
   j = 0
   Sheet1.Unprotect
   Sheet1.Cells.Locked = True
   Sheet1.Range("D3").Locked = False
   Sheet1.Range("D3").Select
   Sheet1.Protect
   End Sub
   ```
4. Now run the macro settings every time you want to enter data to your sheet.

Here is the commented version of the code

```
'The code below should come in a module and should be run every time a change is required in the sheet
Public j 'declaring j as a public variable so that it can be accessed from any procedure in the excel project

Sub Settings()
j = 0 'sets j as zero
Sheet1.Unprotect 'unprotect the sheet
Sheet1.Cells.Locked = True 'locks all the cells in the sheet
Sheet1.Range("D3").Locked = False 'unlocks the first cell D3 and makes it editable
Sheet1.Range("D3").Select 'selects the cell D3
Sheet1.Protect 'reprotects the sheet
End Sub



'Following code should be entered in the code of sheet where the values need to be entered
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range) 'the code runs when a cell in the excel sheet is changed
On Error GoTo enditall 'this handles error
Application.EnableEvents = False 'excel events are disabled
i = Array("D3", "C3", "B9", "B3", "E2", "D4", "G4", "I4", "D5", "G5", "I5", "D6", "G6", "I6", "D7", "G7", "I7", "D8", "G8", "I8") 'array with cells in order
k = Replace(Target.Cells.Address, "$", "") 'finds the cell address where the change was made
If k = i(j) Then 'checks whether the change was made in a cell in the array, we set the value of j to zero by running the macro settings shown below
Sheet1.Unprotect 'unprotects the sheet to make the changes
Sheet1.Range(i(j)).Locked = True 'makes the correspondig cell in the array locked after editing
Sheet1.Range(i(j + 1)).Locked = False 'unlocks the next cell in the array
Sheet1.Range(i(j + 1)).Select 'selects the next cell in the array
j = j + 1 'increments the value of j by 1
Sheet1.Protect 'reprotects the sheet
End If
enditall: 'the code below will run on an error, this code will run when value of j becomes more than the number of elements in array k
Sheet1.Protect 'protect the sheet
Application.EnableEvents = True 'enables excel events
End Sub
```

See the sample file at https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B3mN8H2AV4UCN2E5ZWMxNjEtMGZiZS00NzYzLWI2NDUtOTdmZjg3YzcyNGUw

Comment: I know nothing about defining Macro's, can you tgive me an example of how to control the cell order with two cells?

Comment: Why do you want these data to be entered in that particular order?

Comment: Also, How can I globally search and replace a value in all the formulas within the spreadsheet?

Comment: You have not answered my previous question. :-)

Comment: @FrankComputer: for your last question, you can use Ctrl-H (Search & Remplace) and choose the option `Look into Formulas` and replace what you want.

Comment: Yes, I agree to JMAx. Similarly you can click Ctrl + `(button to the left of 1) and use Ctrl + H

Comment: @KannanS: Sorry for delay, 1. Particular order so that the user just presses enter and is ready to enter the next value. It follows the order in which users would enter their data, thus saving them time in re-positioning the cursor to the appropiate cell.

Comment: Considering the order you want to execute, I don't think you could deal with it without vba. For data validation only, please have a look at my answer

Comment: To me the obvious solution to this requirement is a form.  It would not be difficult to create a form that looks like the screen shot given.  With a form, the designer has total control over sequence, background processing and much else.  There are many websites offering help with the creation of forms but it you want a simple example in an answer I can provide it.  However, if you take this route, you must accept that you are going to have to take the time to learn about macros.

Comment: @KannanS: As for global search and replace of formulas, I'm using Excel 2010 and the Ctrl-H doesn't do anything.. How can I do it via the menu, or is there another key-sequence?

Comment: @FrankComputer: Ctrl-H should work. See http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-use-excel-2010s-find-and-replace-feature.html

Comment: -1 marked down as the question clearly stated order was important

Comment: @brettdj: Now I have provided the order solution too.

Comment: @KannanS I dont understand what you are doing with the code - your j variable is empty and never increments so your `If k = i(j) Then` only runs on D3. You would also need to cater for a target of two or more cells. (NB - I will reverse my down vote for working code)

Comment: Yes you are right. I have mentioned that you have to run the 'settings' macro to edit the sheet (see the fourth point). Settings macro sets the value of j as 0. This will fetch the first cell from the array.

Comment: @brettdj: Please see the sample file at https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B3mN8H2AV4UCN2E5ZWMxNjEtMGZiZS00NzYzLWI2NDUtOTdmZjg3YzcyNGUw

Comment: I'm still not clear on how you are running the order (the sample file is different from your code in the answer) for different values of J. But given your perseverance I will remove my down vote which was for your your original answer not addressing the issue as you are working through this.

Comment: @brettdj: Sample file code and code here are the same. I will comment it when I have time.

Comment: @Kannan S: I plugged in your code, but it failed!.. Perhaps, I didn't do something right? Perhaps I could email you the sheet and you could do me the favor and make it work?.. It would also help me as a tutorial, to understand how it works. Thanks

Comment: @Frank: did you try the sample file give? You may give the url of the file.

Comment: email me at: frankrotolo@yahoo.com and I will reply with the .xls file.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to check the order **without VBA**, you can use **Data Validation** with formulas (this will take some time but you will have **no code to write**).

- Select the second cell you want to check (`C3` in your case)
- In the Ribbon, go to **Data > Data Validation**
- In the `Allow:`, choose **Custom**
- In the field, put this formula: `=IF(ISEMPTY(D3),FALSE,TRUE)`
- In the tab **Error Alert**, change the dialog to explain to the user what he should do, something like:

> You have to fill cell D3 before filling cell C3.

For some extra information about Data Validation, you can have a look [here](http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/excel-2010-data-validation-restricting-data/).

[EDIT] The best way is probably to create vba that will automatically create these validations from an array

Comment: +1 data validation superior to locking entire sheet, plus this method provides the order solution.